# daterangepicker - shows previous selected ranges as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker plugin to get the date ranges. After clicking apply button multiple times, it gives all the previous date ranges which were selected rather than giving the current selected date range. I just need the current selected range instead of all previous ranges. Is it the plugin or is there something missing in code. Can someone suggest a fix. Code and image is mentioned for reference.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFlZC.png

HTML:

```
               <form id="form">
                    <div class="d-flex date_selector">
                        <div id="reportrange" class="form-control">
                        <i style="position: inherit; color: #929292" class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            <span id="date-display"></span> <i style="position: inherit; color: #929292" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn stat-date-submit" id="submit" type="submit">Apply</button>
                    </div>
               </form>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        let data = JSON.parse(`{{community_stats|safe}}`); // Data from controller
        fill_data(data);

        let start = moment().subtract(30, 'days');
        let end = moment();
        $('#reportrange span').text(start.format('MMM D') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM D, YYYY'))
        
        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            maxDate: end,
            autoApply: true,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(30, 'days'), moment()],
                // 'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().add(1, 'days')],
                // 'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, function(start, end) {
            let start_date = start
            console.log("start date in cb: ", start_date)
            let end_date = end
            console.log("end date in cb: ", end_date)

            $('#reportrange span').text(start_date.format('MMM D') + ' - ' + end_date.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
            start_date = start_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            end_date = end_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            console.log("start and end date to submit function: ", start_date, end_date)

            $("#form").submit(function (e) {

            $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#submit").addClass('is-loading');

            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(typeof(start))
            console.log(typeof(end))

            console.log("start date in submit_function: ", start_date)
            console.log("end date in submit function: ", end_date)

            let data_obj = {
                'duration': "custom",
                "start_date": start_date,
                "end_date": end_date
            }

            console.log(data_obj)

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "/analysis/",
                data: data_obj,
                success: function (data) {
                    fill_data(data);
                    $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $("#submit").removeClass('is-loading');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $("#submit").removeClass('is-loading');
                }
            });
        });



        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the submit event handler out of the callback of `daterangepicker` and declare out the variables `start_date` and `end_date`. Else every time you change the date picker values you add an event function on click of submit button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-CryKbMe7sjSCDPl18jtJI5DR5jtkUWxPXWaLCst6QjH8wxDexfRJic2WRmRXmstr2Y8SxDDWuBO6CQC6IE4KTA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">
    <div class="d-flex date_selector">
      <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
      <button class="btn stat-date-submit" id="submit" type="submit">Apply</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      let start = moment().subtract(30, 'days');
      let end = moment();

      let start_date;
      let end_date;

      $("#form").submit(function (e) {

        $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#submit").addClass('is-loading');

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(typeof (start))
        console.log(typeof (end))

        console.log("start date in submit_function: ", start_date)
        console.log("end date in submit function: ", end_date)

        let data_obj = {
          'duration': "custom",
          "start_date": start_date,
          "end_date": end_date
        }

        console.log('--->', data_obj)
      });

      $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        maxDate: end,
        autoApply: true,
        ranges: {
          'Today': [moment(), moment()],
          'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
          'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
          'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(30, 'days'), moment()],
          // 'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().add(1, 'days')],
          // 'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
      }, function (start, end) {
        start_date = start;
        end_date = end;
        console.log("start date in cb: ", start_date)
        console.log("end date in cb: ", end_date)

        $('#reportrange span').text(start_date.format('MMM D') + ' - ' + end_date.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
        start_date = start_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        end_date = end_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        console.log("start and end date to submit function: ", start_date, end_date)
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```